# Kafka connect in docker

Tags: apache-kafka, dockerfile, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to set up a Dockerized environment running kafka-connect and having a standalone connector (s3-sink).

I am using docker-compose and Kafka, zookeeper and my producer all works beautifully, but the docker image for kafka connect shuts down immediately after booting. I used examples from the documentation, but none uses a ENTRYPOINT or CMD.

Further more, when I prevent it to shutdown and try to launch my connector with `./bin/connect-standalone` it fails with the following error `org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector`

My Docker compose is literraly two lines, the first one should be doing what my first problem is, the second is installing what the second issue claims is missing...

Surely I am missing something here in how this is supposed to be working, any idea ?

I prevented the image to shutdown, and it still does not expose anything on port 8083 with kafka-connect REST interface

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:5.3.0
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-s3:5.3.0
COPY . .
#CMD["connect-standalone", "connect-standalone.properties", "s3-sink.properties"]
```

I expect the Docker image to not shutdown and expose port 8083

**Answer** : the rest API is started when a connector is launched. If the connector fails, the api is shut down so will the container.

Comment: I built the image and in the inspect it shows that it exposes port 8083. Probably you are not mapping that port on host? It would be useful to post your docker-compose.yml and any docker and docker-compose commands you run to build the image and run the container

Comment: The `cp-kafka-connect` images already start with S3 connector. Do you need your own?

Comment: I've similar issue, wondering how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest API is started when a connector is launched. If the connector fails, the api is shut down so will the container.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the environment variable CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH to whatever path the plugin is getting installed to.

If you use --verbose on the confluent-hub install command,the plugin is being installed to /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/

The executable is looking in a different folder by default.